# Installing Reporting Services on SQL Server 2008 R2 went wrong

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, ssrs-2008

I installed for the first time reporting services on an instance of SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise edition. The two databases are created and everything seems to be as a flawless installation. But, when I surf to the reporting site (`http://SQLserverName:80/ReportServer_InstanceName`) I only get a few html rendered markup code like title and version, but no user interface like buttons, colors, overviews, menu’s  etc.

The following is the returned HTML code from that url:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="Generator" content="Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services Version 10.0.1600.22">
<title>SQLserverName/ReportServer_InstanceName - /</title>
</head>
<body><H1> SQLserverName /ReportServer_ InstanceName - /</H1><hr>
<pre></pre><hr>
Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services Version 10.0.1600.22 
</body>
</html>
```

I suspect that something went wrong in the installation, but I don't know what exactly. I don’t have any problems with authentication (did it all under domain admin account even for the SQL, ...this is only a test case setup, so I can play with it). Also I'm a noob to this.

Can someone point me out or give me a little hint on this phenomenon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try going to `http://sqlservername/reports`. The report server url (the one you listed) is the web service url.

For more information, please see:

- Report Manager: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157147.aspx
- Report Server: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157231.aspx

Comment: Thanks Brian, the penny has dropped ;)